# HTML is ignoring valign

Tags: html, css

So I am building the final page of an online exhibit I am working on.  The final page uses the exact same format as an earlier page in the exhibit (with an image to the left and a paragraph to the right of the image) so I just copy/pasted all the code and changed URLs, text, and dimensions of images and td elements as I needed to.  I have changed nothing to do with the alignment of the various elements on the page, but now I have an element that is basically ignoring *td valign="top"* and appears to be aligned to center instead.  I've done a line by line comparison of the html of the new page with the original but I can't find anything that should have changed it.  Basically the text part of the page (*title of page* and *body of page*) should start on the same line as the top of the image, but instead it's starting in the center after a huge amount of white space.

Here's the particular table in question with the text and full URLs removed to make it a bit shorter:

```
<table width="917" border="0"></br>
<tr>
  <td width="400" valign="top">                
    <table width="10" border="1" align="center" bordercolor="#8AC3C9">
        <tr>
          <td width="184" bordercolor="#8AC3C9"><div align="center"><a href="*image*" target="_blank"><img src="*image*" alt="image" width="400" height="267" hspace="1" vspace="1" border="0" align="middle"></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bordercolor="#8AC3C9" bgcolor="#8AC3C9"><div align="center" class="style2">*Image*</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
        </div>        
    </td>
  <td width="500" "valign="top"><div align="center"><font size="+2" face="Georgia"><b>*Title of page*</b></font></div></br>
  <div align="justify"><font face="Georgia">*Body of page*
    </div></td>          
</tr>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout.  Instead, use flex.

Comment: Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). You have a rogue `"` in front of your attribute name. (Also please learn CSS, it isn't 1995 any more).

Comment: That did it, thanks.  Also, I know next to nothing about html.  I've basically been teaching myself from scratch by scavenging older parts of our website.  (I work for a public library).  The whole thing is going to get migrated to Wordpress in the next few months so old bad code won't be an issue for much longer anyway.

Comment: I don't recommend using tables either, but I have to say that pattern recognition is a very valuable skill if you're learning HTML :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a " in front of valign, so it's not reading the attribute.

```
<td width="500" "valign="top"><div align="center">
```

The full code should be:

```
<table width="917" border="0"></br>
<tr>
  <td width="400" valign="top">                
    <table width="10" border="1" align="center" bordercolor="#8AC3C9">
        <tr>
          <td width="184" bordercolor="#8AC3C9"><div align="center"><a href="image.htm" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x267" alt="image" width="400" height="267" hspace="1" vspace="1" border="0" align="middle"></a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bordercolor="#8AC3C9" bgcolor="#8AC3C9"><div align="center" class="style2">*Image*</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
        </div>        
    </td>
  <td width="500" "valign="top"><div align="center"><font size="+2" face="Georgia"><b>*Title of page*</b></font></div></br>
  <div align="justify"><font face="Georgia">*Body of page*
    </div></td>          
</tr>
```

Here's a working codepen: http://codepen.io/vic3685/full/vyKmwg/

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Can you tag it as answered? Thanks!